# error in OAUTH2 Credential when inserting an event in Calendar API: OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access token

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am a student and fairly new with the handling of APIs and I am trying to use the google calendar API to insert events in a calendar from the backend of a web application with SpringBoot, after reading the documentation regarding OAuth2 I got to this point. The error appears when calling the Calendar service, and it must be regarding the handling of the refresh tokens. I only found one question that is similar to this but I couldn't extract any solutions. In the absence of examples of how to use the API with the access token in this case, I post my first question on StackOverflow.
Im sorry in advance, This may be terribly wrong. Please enlighten me with your knowledge

> 2021-03-14 16:38:13.479 ERROR 9716 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access token. An instance
> with a new access token should be used, or a derived type that supports refreshing.]

This is the code, the example that appears for Java is 'depreceated' so I tried to solve it this way. What I'm trying to do is, first get an access token through the endpoint provided by the google api, sending the client's data as well as the secret and then get the response. Based on the oauth2 server's answer, I generate an AccessToken and then create the service through the CalendarBuilder. After this I create an event for testing and then execute the insert statement.

````
try {
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token")
                    .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .body("grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=********&client_secret=*********&code=*********&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/handle_auth")
                    .asJson();
            JSONObject myObj = response.getBody().getObject();
            Date expiry = new Date();
            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(myObj.getString("access_token"), expiry);

            GoogleCredentials credential = new GoogleCredentials(accessToken);
            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential);
            System.out.println(accessToken);
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                    requestInitializer).setApplicationName("prueba").build();

            Event event = new Event().setSummary("Ejemplo 123")
                    .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103");
   DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime).setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
            event.setStart(start);

            DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime).setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
            event.setEnd(end);
            
            event = service.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
            System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());

        } catch (UnirestException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } ```
````

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications

Comment: How are you trying to refresh the access token? @thomydiaz